# BASH sed/grep script needed to grab text between two known words which include back slashes and single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a javascript map file for mobile test automation in which page elements are mapped out like so:

```
shop_myBoutique: {
      self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
    },
```

The problem in the line above is the trailing comment: // self:

These illegal inline comments are causing socket errors at runtime. So, I need to write a shell script which will parse a map file (which can contains thousands of mapped elements) and grab every line with an illegal trailing comment so I can go edit and correct the comment. I want a script that will print out everything from the first "self:" thru to the final "// self:" including the beginning word, self: and the ending word, self:.

The output would look like so:

```
self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
```

I've tried the following sed and grep regex attempts, but clearly I suck because they all fail (the $textComments variable contains the contents of an entire test automation map file where all elements of a given page in a mobile app have been mapped with selectors):

```
# echo "$testComments" | sed -n '/self: /,/self: /p' > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | sed -e "s/.*self: '\([^']*\)'>.*self: /\1/p" > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | sed -n "/self:/,/self:/p" > myComments.txt
# sed -n "/self: /,/self: /p" > myComments.txt
# grep -o '(?<=self) (?s).*(?=self)' $testComments > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | sed -e 's/self: \(.*\)\/\/ self:/\1/' | grep '.*self' > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | grep '.*self' > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | sed '([self: ]+).*([self: ]+)' | grep '.*self:'
# echo "$testComments" | sed 's/\(^self:).*( self: $\)' > myComments.txt
# echo "$testComments" | sed '/self: /,/'\\ self: /p' > myComments.txt
echo "$testComments" | grep '(?<=(self: )).*(?= self:)' | grep -o '^[^ ]*' > myComments.txt
```

Comment: Good show! including your tests so far. You can save time by skipping the `> myComments.txt` and just let the output flow to the screen. Add `>` once you think you have it working. It would be easier if you could reduce the width of you line, (but keep the complexity that is causing you trouble. Also, I'm pretty sure that `/srchTarg/,/srchTarg/....` is only effective on multiline input. You can test this for yourself by making super simipe test cases and see if you need to have multiline input for the "range" to fire. ... testing your code. back in a while. Good luck.

Comment: I can't see a difference between the code in the code block and your "The output would look like this". Don't you want to remove the trailing `// self:` ? Rather than reply in comments, please fix your question above (-; . Good luck.

Comment: `echo "$testComments" | sed 's@// self: *$@@' ` Output=`self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")'` Going to bed. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I want to include the trailing comment // and the keyword self: in the returned findings. The point of this effort is not to eliminate these trailing comments, but to locate them in whatever map file I parse and then go in and put these comments on their own line. Typically a full trailing comment will look like so: // self: `android=new UiSelector().resourceId("${process.env}:id/txt_title").text("Dance Party")`

Comment: So you're looking to remove the "function" wrapper code? `shop_myBoutique: {` and `}`? And that complete text will get stored in an env var (`${testComments}` in this case)? Could you just search for lines with `// self:$` at the end? (Tne `sed -n '@// self:$/p' file* >> bigList.txt` Got to go.

Comment: Thanks for this! I want to grab the first "self: " and whatever comes after it as well, along with the trailing "// self:" as well. This will make it easy to then go find the lines that need editing in the map files I parse. I can copy the line I want in the output file and then just go find that line in the map file and do the editing that I want.

Comment: How about displaying all lines which just end in `// self:`? If the result is to your taste (i.e. no false positives), you could use `sed` to simply remove all those offending `// self`, leaving the rest of the line intact.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- we're looking for lines with the format: `<label>: ...some_text... // <label>:`
- tokens of interest are the leading/trailing `<label>:`
- matching`<label>:` tokens reside on the same line
- `<label>` could be any set of characters except dual forward slashes (`//`) (eg, `self:`, `this is ok:`)

Adding a few more lines to the input:

```
$ cat testComments
shop_myBoutique: {
      self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
    },

shop_myBoutique: {
      other: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // other:
    },
      this is ok: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this // this is ok:
      ignore this: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this
      ignore: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this:
```

My `sed` skills aren't up to this task so I'll use `awk`:

```
awk -F'//' '                                             # field delimiter is "//"
NF>1 { line=$0                                           # if more than 1 field then make a copy of the current line
       last=$NF                                          # make copy of the last field
       gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",line)                     # strip leading white space from "line"
       gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",last)       # strip leading/trailing white space from "last"
       if (last ~ /:$/ && index(line,last)==1)           # if "last" ends with a ":" and also shows up in position #1 of "line" then ...
          print $0                                       # print the current line
     }
' testComments
```

This generates:

```
      self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
      other: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // other:
      this is ok: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this // this is ok:
```

---

OK, so that's a lot of typing; I'd recommend wrapping this in a `bash` function:

```
find_comments() {
    awk -F'//' '
    NF>1 { line=$0
           last=$NF
           gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",line)
           gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",last)
           if (last ~ /:$/ && index(line,last)==1)
              print $0
         }
    ' "${@:--}"
}
```

Testing with a file:

```
$ find_comments testComments
      self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
      other: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // other:
      this is ok: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this // this is ok:
```

Testing with stdin:

```
$ cat testComments | find_comments
      self: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // self:
      other: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // other:
      this is ok: 'android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("My Boutique")' // ignore this // this is ok:
```